# Elements inside <td style="

Tags: css, styles

I'm trying to put the `colspan`, `valign` and `align` in the following piece

`<td style="background-color:#000333" colspan="4" valign="middle" align="center">`

all inside the `style="..."`, to have something like:

`<td style="background-color:#000333;colspan:4;valign:'middle'; align:'center'>`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why? Which problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: This is a code generated by a python script. I would like to put all the attributes inside the line and not have to create a CSS entry, but it seems not possible.

Comment: I don’t see how this would avoid creating a CSS entry (whatever that means) – you would be using more CSS, not less – and what purpose would that serve.

Comment: I have a huge style.css created by the theme I'm using, plus some added by myself in the child theme, so, once this python script is only activated sometimes, I was thinking about not make the style.css even bigger. But I'll take your and the other's advice and use more CSS. But, still, not have a colspan is a problem...

Comment: The question asks how to replace HTML attributes by inline CSS. I cannot see how that would affect the size of an external stylesheet. It would *increase* the amount of your CSS code a little.

Comment: Just for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You will be unable to achieve colpan results with CSS</del> I stand corrected, you can in CSS3. But `text-align:center` will get and `vertical-align:middle` for vertical alignment.

With that said, please consider using proper CSS rather than stuffing things into the style tags, that will make your (and everybody else's) job much easier in the future. That is as simple as saying

```
<td class='myclass'>
```

and then inside your CSS file

```
td.myclass
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: You cannot replace `colspan` by CSS (an answer saying you could has been deleted by its owner).

Comment: Thank you @Jukka and Volodya. The box says to avoid it, but once I don't have reputation to give a +1 to the answer, I'm thank you here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because there is no way in CSS to do the job of `colspan` (except in a special case where its value equals the total number of columns, and even then only using a proposed CSS extension that does not work consistently across modern browsers, not to mention old browsers).